# Solving for x in a matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm confused, how exactly can I solve this? I have no clue where to start

> Solve for $X$
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}6&8&-6\\1&7&2\end{bmatrix} = 2X - 3\begin{bmatrix}-5&-2&-6\\4&9&-2\end{bmatrix}$

How on earth can i solve this? I'm assuming $X$ is some matrix they want me to find that satisfies the matrix that is set = to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View the problem as $$A=2X-3B$$
$$X=\frac12 \left(A+3B\right)$$

Comment: Ahah! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SiongthyeGoh for the hint;

I obtained the solution 
$X = \begin{bmatrix} -9/2&1&-12\\13/2&17&-2\end{bmatrix}$